# Problem with recurring namespace-names

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a class named `AppVisum.Membership.Views.AppVisum.Membership.Controllers.Membership._Page_Views_AppVisum_Membership_Controllers_Membership_Validate_cshtml`. Yeah, I know it is hidious, but I rather think it has to be named that, and as for the namespaces, those are unnecessary, but the class is generated by a tool, and the folder needs to be named `AppVisum.Membership.Controllers.Membership`, so I don't know if I can change the namespaces. However, hideous names isn't the real problem, the main issue is getting to the class `AppVisum.Sys.AppSys`. The ide tells me that it can't find `AppVisum.Membership.Views.AppVisum.Sys.AppSys`, so how can I tell it that I want the root one?

#### [Edit]

Sorry I wasn't specific enough as I thought this would be a simple problem to solve. The global:: would've worked perfectly if this had been a normal .cs file, however, it's a razor-file and razor don't quite like `@using global::AppVisum.Sys` (that just translates to using global, which doesn't make any sense). I've found 2 possible solutions, the first is to simply change the rule that search for files to search for folders with `_` instead of `.`. Then I'd get paths like `AppVisum.Membership.Views.AppVisum_Membership_Controllers_Membership._Page_Views_AppVisum_Membership_Controllers_Membership_Validate_cshtml`. This would probably work just fine, and unless someone comes up with a better alternative I think I'm going for that. Another option is to rewrite the custom-tool that generates the classes (it's opensource, so I think I should be able to do that too fairly simply). Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: You should change your assembly's Default Namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `global::` prefix to the namespace.

Comment: Any way to make that work with razor? It doesn't accept `@using global::AppVisum.Sys` :-/

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
using Sys = AppVisum.Sys;
```

or:

```
using AppSys = AppVisum.Sys.AppSys;
```

Basically, you can reduce ambiguity by aliasing types and namespaces in your `using` directives.  (And the aliases don't need to be the same as the type/namespace names, they just are in my examples.)

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks mentions in a comment, you should basically fix your project's default namespace - either that, or avoid creating the folder hierarchy. You've tagged this question with C#, but is your generated code actually in VB? While the VB compiler prepends the project's namespace when compiling, I don't believe the C# compiler does, so I'm surprised you're getting this namespace to be honest.

I disagree with your claim that "hideous names isn't the real problem" - I'd say it *is* the real problem, and making it hard to get at a particular namespace is one *consequence* of the problem. Fix the real problem (the bad namespaces) and the rest will go away. Using `global::` etc is just a workaround, and one that you'll need to apply all over the place. It would be better to sort this out once and for all.

Basically if you can tell us more about how you've got into this situation, we're more likely to be able to help you get out of it.

Comment: Well, basically it's about compiling razor views for a application-framework I'm writing (namely AppVisum). However, as is now AppVisum requires all compiled plugin-views to be placed in a folder named like so: `~/Views/<ControllerFullName>/`. In other word, I have a controller named Membership inside a project named AppVisum.Membership inside a folder named Controllers, so the fullname of the controller is AppVisum.Membership.Controllers.Membership. This is to make sure that views don't collide with each other, like both membership and user can have a view named edit.cshtml.

Comment: @alexandr: But you can still change the default namespace (which is separate from the project name)

Comment: Yeah, but the default namespace should be AppVisum.Membership as that is what the project is. It's the membership-plugin for AppVisum, and I don't really want to change that. It's how I've structured all of my project-parts.

Comment: @Alxandr: The namespace or the assembly name?

Comment: Both if I understand your question correctly. I can try to explain a bit more how the project is built up, but it'll take some time.

Comment: @Jon: Oh, and yes, it's a C# project. All of the projects in the solution uses c# for it's primary language, and the files used to generate the file in question is a .cshtml file.

Comment: @Alxandr: Okay, so it sounds like it's Razor that's inferring the namespace from the folder hierarchy. Do you know if you can specify it explicitly? If so, that's your answer. It does sound like things are a bit messed up though - why do you have a *Controllers* folder inside a *Views* folder? Is this a controller or a view? It shouldn't be both, surely. And if the project already has a name of AppVisum.Membership, I don't think that part of the name *should* be generated again inside the folder hierarchy.

Comment: @Jon. No, no, the Controllers-folder is besides the Views-folder. However, the folder inside the Views-folder (in other word the folder that specifies *which* controller to use in .net-mvc) is named the **fullname** of the controller (my custom naming-rule). In other word, the controller is `~/Controllers/Membership.cs`, and the view is `~/Views/AppVisum.Membership.Controllers.Membership/Validate.cshtml` which translates to that odd class-path.

Comment: @Jon: A copy of the project can be found here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2306001/AppVisum.zip if you would like to look at it. I can pretty much explain the logic behind it all to, but it'll probably take some time as the project is getting a bit complex, and this problem is present because of several parts of the project, like the mapping-handler, and the custom ControllerFactory.

Comment: @Jon: Another solution to the problem could be to rename the `AppVisum.Membership.Controllers.Membership`-folder to something else entirely, however, I need that to be something that is unique for a single class across several projects, and doesn't change on every compilation/change.

Comment: @Alxandr: If this is all due to your custom naming rule, then that sounds like the thing to fix. A naming rule which ends up with a view inside a folder containing the word "Controllers" sounds like a really bad idea to me, to be very blunt. It sounds like it should simply be under ~/Views/Membership to me - it's a view dealing with membership, right?

Comment: Yeah, but it's plugin-based, so if another person makes a blog-plugin (for instance), it's not to far-fetched to think that he'd want a Membership-controller and a Membership-folder too, and then we'd have collisions. That's what I've been trying to solve.

Comment: @Alxandr: Then they should be able to make *their* plugin have a different top level namespace rather than AppVisum (as they will be plugging into AppVisum rather than being part of the AppVisum codebase). Think what the namespaces should logically be, and then work out how to achieve that - at the moment the namespaces really don't sound logical.

Comment: @Jon: Yeah, I get that, but I'd like to have my plugins start with AppVisum. Still, if it's no good way to solve it maybe I need to rethink it.

Comment: @Alxandr: If I were a third party developing a plugin, I wouldn't want to be forced to use *your* namespace. My code wouldn't be part of AppVisum. It's just inappropriate, IMO.

Comment: @Jon: Yeah, of cause, any third party plugin shouldn't be named AppVisum at all! And plugins that don't have AppVisum in their name don't cause problems with the generator. Only the ones with AppVisum in their name does.

Comment: @Alxandr: But why would you need AppVisum in there *twice* then? You only need it once to show that it's part of the AppVisum project. Think about whether a namespace really makes sense - can you think of any *real* reason why "AppVisum.Membership.Views.AppVisum.Membership.Controllers.Membership" is a good namespace? It's got repetition (AppVisum.Membership twice) *and* contradiction (Views or Controllers? shouldn't be both).

Comment: Yeah, I know. And the project namespace is only AppVisum.Membership. The problem is that I need a distinct way to name all controllers in all plugins, and the way I made that is to use their full name. Then the views would have to be put in a folder with the controllers full name, which causes the horrid namespace. If you got a good idea as of how I can with a string separate the controllers (they can have the same name in different projects), than I'd gladly hear it, cause I'm about out of ideas. Remember, the name needs to be given to a folder with views in it.

Comment: Went for the _ instead of ., so now I have `AppVisum.Membership.Views.AppVisum_Membership_Controllers_Membership` as the view-namespace. Not pretty that either, but it works and meets all the requirements. If you got a better idea I'd love to hear it, but remember that making sure that collision in names is what's most important (after making sure it compiles and runs).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can simplify by adding an using alias :

```
using AV = AppVisum.Membership.Views.AppVisum;
```

and in the code :

```
var s = new AV.Sys.AppSys();
```

Comment: The class AppSys is in global::AppVisum.Sys.